# Using SurfaceView in Cordova plugin

Tags: android, plugins, cordova

I want to use SurfaceView in PhoneGap CordovaPlugin. I am able to dynamically add SurfaceView, but it is on top of my UI (HTML). I'd like to use SurfaceView as background and create web content on top of that. How can I set SurfaceView behind Cordova content.

Current code:

```
final Activity activity = cordova.getActivity();

activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        SurfaceView surfaceView = new SurfaceView(activity);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);

        activity.addContentView(surfaceView, params);

        callbackContext.success(); // Thread-safe.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use addContentView() to add your SurfaceView, it will be always add to the top.
Get the content view and add to the bottom.

```
ViewGroup viewGroup =  ((ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content));
viewGroup.addView(surfaceView, 0, params);
```